# Trying to include log and trig functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm very new to this, trying to make a function for Google Sheets based on a formula that has several uses of a log base 10 and sin and cos functions, but I guess just using log(x,10) and sin and cos like the sheet formulas doesn't work. What syntax do I need to use those functions?

Comment: You have to mention what code you wrote, what errors you got and what exactly doesn't work. Without that, its not easy to answer questions. btw, don't guess. try it out for yourself and post the results.

Answer (score 4):

Inside script editor If you type in `Math.` you will see many math formulas that can be used inside app scripts.
[image]